# Passing java.lang.Long to Integer constructor

Tags: clojure

```
(Integer. 1)
```

As I understand it is the same as following Java code:

```
new Integer(1)
```

So now I have got following construction

```
(Integer. (Long. 1))
#=> 1
```

How does this work? Java Integer class has got [two constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and they don't accept `Long`.

By the way, following doesn't work:

```
(Long. (Integer. 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed seems like a bug in Clojure. For Java, it's the other way around. This seems related to [CLJ-445](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-445), an "enhancement" request that is over five years old. It's perhaps best to ping that issue with this trivial example.

---

`new Long(new Integer(1))` should be acceptable due to a combination of [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and [widening](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

With unboxing (the inverse of autoboxing), some objects are implicitly converted to primitive types:

> Converting an object of a wrapper type (Integer) to its corresponding primitive (int) value is called unboxing. The Java compiler applies unboxing when an object of a wrapper class is:
>
> - Passed as a parameter to a method that expects a value of the corresponding primitive type.
> - Assigned to a variable of the corresponding primitive type.

In this example, `Integer` objects are implicitly reduced to `int`, and `Long` objects are implicitly reduced to `long`.

With widening, primitive types can be implicitly converted to "wider" primitive types when this is possible without information loss. This means that an `int` can be converted to a `long`, but not the other way around, so `new Integer(new Long(1))` should be rejected.

Comment: Ok. Java automatically unboxes Integer/Long types. It is ok. But widening is suppose to be `int to long, float, or double` but not the way I do it in the example (`long -> int`)

Comment: Wait, you're right. This seems to go the other way around. That's a bit weird indeed.

Comment: @fl00r Interestingly enough, when I try this in Java, `javac` complains about `new Integer(new Long(1))` and accepts `new Long(new Integer(1))`, as expected.

Comment: Ok, I got this piece of Java code that casts long to int https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L1169

Comment: @fl00r I'm not too familiar with the Clojure source code, but seeing how it complains about `clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor`, I think the problem is in the type logic rather than the conversion functions in `clojure.lang.RT`.

Comment: @fl00r I think the problem is here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Reflector.java#L465 both `Long` and `long` may convert to `int` (which seems very wrong), but only `int` may convert to `long` (while `Integer` should be listed explicitly for this to work).